# Change name of "New Entry" button

Tags: control-panel, craft-features

is it possible to change the name of the "New Entry" button?

In my case the user can add a new program part. And so the button should call "New program" or something like that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this without hacking core files using Craft's [static translation](http://buildwithcraft.com/help/static-translations) support.

Answer (score 0):

I have a way to do this. But i think its not the best:

Change line 21 and 31 in craft/app/templates/entries/index.html

I fear a new update will turn it back. But maybe not...

Comment: A new update will overwrite it. Probably best to add a feature request here http://feedback.buildwithcraft.com/forums/285221-feature-requests